# why are the structs in c++ used as a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++, struct

```
struct Node{
    int val;
    Node* next;
};
```

we use this struct as Node* node and not Node node.why?
any link to a reference would also be appreciated

Comment: Because the definition of `Node` can't occur recursively.

Comment: `Node*` is not a struct used as a pointer.  It's just a pointer, and that pointer points to a Node (or is nullptr, or is uninitialized, or is a dangling pointer to an object that no longer exists at that address).

Comment: If you had `Node next;` a each Node would always contain another node containing another node ... to infinity. You can't create such a structure that requires infinite size.

Comment: There might not be a next node and you need a way to express that. The most obvious way is to have `next` be `nullptr`

Comment: In C++ you not only have the option to use a reference instead of a pointer, you may choose to use a smart pointer. Alternatively, you could use one of the existing containers instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.
This is sample for make a link list struct.
When you want to make a list with count of list is not defined.
you can using struct:  Node *next pointer.
this pointer will be save address of next element of list.
So that, you can access next element from head element.
if you use Node next;  next is only a variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The other comments already pointed this out, somewhat. When you define a struct, the compiler needs to know how much memory is needed to store an object of this new struct type.

However, if your struct contains another struct of the same type (direct or indirect) the compiler is unable to calculate the size needed for instantiating an object (understandably, since its size would vary depending on how many times this is chained).

So in order to be able to allocate enough memory for an object, you need to use a pointer. The size of this pointer in memory is known at compile time (no matter where it points at, even if it is Null), so the compiler knows how much memory to allocate for each Node object you create.